# Class Destructors not being called in the expected reverse order from which they were initialized in

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I was testing out smart pointers and how they work and I ran into an "issue". Here is the code which I will be talking about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class B; // forward declaration

class A {

private:
    std::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr;

public:
    void set_B(std::shared_ptr<B> &b) {

        b_ptr = b;
        std::cout << b_ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
    }

    A() { std::cout << "A Constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "A Destructor" << std::endl; }

};

class B {

private:
    std::weak_ptr<A> a_ptr;

public:
    void set_A(std::shared_ptr<A> &a) {

        a_ptr = a;
        std::cout << a_ptr.use_count() << std::endl;
    }

    B() { std::cout << "B Constructor" << std::endl; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "B Destructor" << std::endl; }

};

int main() {

    std::shared_ptr<A> a{std::make_shared<A>()};
    std::shared_ptr<B> b{std::make_shared<B>()};

    a->set_B(b);
    b->set_A(a);

    return 0;

}
```

And here is the output when ran:

```
A Constructor
B Constructor
2
1
A Destructor
B Destructor
```

Now my question is why are the destructors not being called in reverse order from when they are initialized in, e.g (**this is what I expected for the output to be**):

```
A Constructor
B Constructor
2
1
B Destructor
A Destructor
```

The above output is what I was expecting but that wasn't the case. What I could come up with was the following:

- variable `b` goes out of scope (as expected)
- but it has two strong references so the dynamically allocated object which `b` was pointing to is not destroyed yet the object `b` itself as a `std::shared_ptr` object is destroyed and so that leaves only 1 strong reference on that dynamically allocated `B` type object
- the variable `a` goes out of scope following the events above, and it in-turn has only 1 strong reference due to the `std::weak_ptr` not affecting a `std::share_ptr`'s lifetime/use_count, that means that the dynamically allocated `A` type object is destructed... but that is where I wonder how the B destructor gets called after the A one it just doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: Please print the value of `this` instead of just "x Constructor" and "x Destructor".  You will get a much better picture of what is actually being created and destroyed.  With what you're printing now, there is no clear indication of which `A` and which `B` is getting created or destroyed, and at what time.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will make sure to do so from now on when ever possible, I have now changed the output for all of them accordingly to something like this: (e.g the A class constructor) `std::cout << "A Constructor: " << this << std::endl;`

Comment: OK.  The printing of  `this` is to ensure that you are actually tracking all of the `A` and `B` objects being created / destroyed, including temporary ones.

Comment: Class constructors run after member constructors, and class destructors run before member destructors. The `A` destructor runs first, and then the `A::b_ptr` is destructed, and it is the destruction of `b_ptr` that destructs B. See [C++ FAQ "What’s the order that sub-objects of an object are destructed?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#order-dtors-for-members)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A owns a reference to B.

Your `main` scope owns a reference to `A` and `B`.  When `main` ends it drops the `B` reference, then the `A`.

The `B` reference drops the reference count to 1.  The `A` to 0.  `A`s destructor then runs.

After the body of the destructor runs, each member is destroyed.  `A`s reference to `B` goes away.  `B`s destructor is called.

Thus the order you see.